# Can we avoid international money transfer fees by using Venmo or Paypal?

Tags: money-transfer, fees, international-transfer

I have clients in Turkey that send me money via international bank transfer.  All banks have a swift code that is used for international transfers.  The fees charged are in the 70 USD range for the amounts sent to me.  Has anyone used Venmo or Paypal for personal international money transfer and had to pay fees?  If so, what were the amounts of the fees, and how were they determined?

I reside in the USA and have used PayPal to send money as a gift domestically and there is no fee.  I haven't used Venmo yet, but I hear it is totally free also and easier to use than PayPal.

To my understanding, all international bank transfers go through SWIFT in Belgium, thus the fees.  So, this may be wishful thinking on my part.  I'm particularly interested in Turkey to USA transfers, but welcome all experiences.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is seeking a product recommendation. Here's some resources that may help you: https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/banking/faq-send-money-individual/

Comment: The title question isn't a product/service recommendation. If the body of the question was edited to match the title question, specifically whether there are fees for international transfers with these services, that would stay on-topic in my opinion.

Comment: @Nathan L  I have modified the body per your recommendations.  Is it more on-topic now?

Comment: @Michael C  What is wrong with seeking recommendations based on real experiences.?  These are the answers that are really useful.  Otherwise we are left with web resources that may be biased.

Comment: @0tyranny0poverty You were asking for preferences, which is opinion based and seeking for recommendations. But since you've edited your question, it is more on-topic.

Comment: @Michael C  I have encountered similar interventions by moderators on other SE sites.  I am seeking testimonials form users experiences.  Sure there can be some opinion involved but no more so than the service provider's or the manufacturer's official web sites.  These official websites rarely say anything negative about their product or service.  Our questions and answers on SE are rated for the most part on opinions, so why the double standard when seeking opinions and testimonials on products and services?  Is SE doing this for legal reasons to avoid liability issues?

Comment: Paypal's fees are published. They take currency conversion fees (always) as well as fees depending on the account type. If your total accumulated amount transferred (IIRC) exceeds some threshold you must convert to a fee account. Be aware that they have set up their web pages, in an apparently deceptive manner, to default to converting money requests made in (say) USD into local currency, thus increasing their 'take'. A double conversion will probably lose 5%+. This is analogous to their default sourcing from balance or bank balance rather than credit card, also increasing their 'take'.

Comment: @0tyranny0poverty From just my initial research, Paypal charges a fee. Venmo does not if it is money already in a Venmo account, or if you use a debit card or US based bank transfers. The link I included in my first comment has some resources that may be beneficial.

Comment: AFAICT, the chief international payment system is SWIFT in Belgium, not BIS. BIS is for Central banks (ECB, FED, basically the issuers of currencies), not for commercial banks.

Comment: Voting to close because heaven forbid somebody actually get some practical use out of this site. How dare you, OP? What, you think we're here to *help you* or something? (Yes you will avoid the bank fees but paypal can have their own annoying rules and fees, watch out)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with seeking recommendations based on real experiences, it's just that this website is not the platform for that. The Idea of Stack Exchange is to create a repository of answers that will remain useful for years to come, and the powers that be have determined that product recommendations go out of date too quickly to remain useful in the long term. See the [help section](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of explicit fees for sending to someone in a different **country**, however I do believe there are fees for sending from one *currency* to another.

The best option here would be to contact the provider you're interested in using, directly, to request this information from them.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Venmo help online:

> **Venmo is currently only supported within the U.S.** If you try to sign
> in while abroad, you’ll likely get an error message. We will be able
> to further assist you with any login issues upon your return to the
> U.S.

From Forbes:

> Venmo has three main requirements for using the app. You must:
> Be located in the U.S.
> Have a U.S. cell phone that can send and receive text messages using short codes; in the U.S., short codes are five- or six-digit
> numbers for texting
> Be at least 18 years old (in most cases)

This sounds as if Venmo is not supported in Turkey.
From what I understand, Venmo is just creating an ACH transfer...though details are hard to find.